# Как включить js скрипт только на главной странице сайта?

Tags: javascript

Как включить js скрипт только на главной странице сайта средствами js.
Если мы находимся на главной странице вида site.ru или site.ru/index.php , то скрипт выполняется, а на всех остальных не выполняется...

Или например такой вариант. Если на странице присутствует какой-нибудь блок с классом     **class="script_no"** то скрипт не выполняется, если этого блока нет, то выполняется...

Comment: `if ($(".script_no").length == 0) { <execute script> }`

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что надо.